# How can I prevent my Phonegap app from playing video full screen on ios?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I'm making a Phonegap app and I'm using [embed.ly](http://embed.ly). Embed.ly takes a video link and embeds the video on your page. Here is the code below that does this:

```
$.embedly.defaults.key = 'my unique key is here';

$(document).ready(function () {
var url = urlaft; //the url variable contains the video url like youtube 

var urladd = '<li><a href="' + url + '"></a></li>';

document.getElementById("videobox").innerHTML = urladd;

$('a').embedly({query: {maxheight: 195}, 'method':'after'});

$('.embedly-embed').attr('webkit-playsinline', '');

});
```

As you can see, I tried to attach a webkit-playsinline attribute out of desperation to the iframe embed.ly adds the video to although I know that webkit-playsinline should only work on video tags. Is there any way I can keep a video confined to a certain height and width and not go to full screen?

Comment: if its playing in safari it will always go full screen. If the web app is saved to your home screen, I think it will play inline. It is very unfortunate. I too have really disliked this behavior

Comment: It's a phonegap app, no safari

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap utilizes UIWebView, and UIWebview has a property called allowsInlineMediaPlayback (defaults to NO on iPhone).

According to Apple's docs, setting this value to YES and the video element in the HTML document must also include the webkit-playsinline attribute.